# Excel - unique combination

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
Comp  Fund  Date       Value
A     X     30/09/2022 12
B     X     30/09/2022 15
E     X     30/09/2022 31
A     X     31/12/2022 10
B     X     31/12/2022 20
C     X     31/12/2022 15
D     Y     31/12/2022 22
```

I need to output, using formulas (not macros, nor filters, nor manual data manipulation), all of the combination of Companies and Funds and value, for a pre-determined date. THE VALUE SHOULD BE ZERO if there is no entry for such a date.

For a chosen date of 31/12/2022 (for example, in cell F1), for example, the output should be

```
Comp  Fund  Value
E     X     0
A     X     10
B     X     20
C     X     15
D     Y     22
```

I've tried to use a unique combination of Comp and Fund, which didn't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @SolarMike, but this has nothing to do with that I am looking for

Comment: That's fine, I just thought it would give you a nudge towards getting the results you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this using a combination of `HSTACK()` and `BYROW()` functions as shown in below:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `G4`

```
=LET(α,SORT(UNIQUE(A2:B8)),σ,G2,
HSTACK(α,BYROW(α,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(1,(TAKE(x,,1)=A2:A8)*(TAKE(x,,-1)=B2:B8)*(σ=C2:C8),D2:D8,0)))))
```

---

[image]

---

```
=LET(
α,A2:A8,
ß,B2:B8,
Δ,C2:C8,
Θ,D2:D8,
Φ,G2,
ε,SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(α,ß))),
VSTACK({"Comp","Fund","Value"},
HSTACK(ε,BYROW(ε,LAMBDA(x,
XLOOKUP(1,(TAKE(x,,1)=α)*(TAKE(x,,-1)=ß)*(Φ=Δ),Θ,0))))))
```

---

The idea of using <kbd>Greek Letters</kbd> has been taken from **[Jos Woolley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17007704/jos-woolley)** Sir, I found it looks **cool** while assigning names to calculation results and variables.

---

Comment: Another pro for using the Greek letters is that if you want to use the formula in VBA coding, some letters may stand for something (example: `c` will be interpreted as Column argument inside .formula2R1C1). A con to me personally is that the letters are less recognizable than `regular` letters.

Comment: Agree, but using within `LET()` it looks better, I see Jos Sir uses it, which really makes out of the box.

Comment: Great solution @MayukhBhattacharya I just have couple of questions, I guess if some value is zero, you don't have a way to distinguish this scenario, correct?, so I would say that would be an assumption. Why do you need `SORT`? the solution doesn't require to be sorted, correct? Thanks

Comment: It will work without `SORT()` ing as well. If some value is zero, yes it wouldn't be able to distinguish but yes again, the dates which signifies whether or not on a given date for a specific comp there was a fund raised/available or not, which does helps to identify. Also if i don't use `0` it would return `N/A!` which means that particular comp had no fund for a given date. hence to avoid the error i have used to show a `0`. Afaik as per OP -- **`THE VALUE SHOULD BE ZERO if there is no entry for such a date.`**

Comment: Ok, what do you get when you remove the `0` from the `FILTER()` function? Mentioning about the short formula **1** . 135 bytes, **2**. 207. bytes. **[Check Here](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter)**

Comment: true, as I said it is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach, it assumes for a given lookup date (`lk`) there are no more than one unique combination of **Comp** and **Fund** column values, as it is in the sample of the question.

```
=LET(lk,F1, data,A2:D8, abUx,UNIQUE(TAKE(data,,2)),
 VSTACK({"Comp","Fund","Value"}, HSTACK(abUx, BYROW(abUx, LAMBDA(x,
  FILTER(TAKE(data,,-1), (INDEX(data,,3)=lk)
   * (MMULT(N(TAKE(data,,2)=x),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(abUx),,,0))=2),0))))))
```

**Note**: Since we are considering unique elements for two columns only, you can replace the `SEQUENCE` call with just: `{1;1}` which result in a shorter formula if you prefer.

You can avoid using `MMULT` adding additional conditions to the `FILTER` as follows:

```
=LET(lk,F1, data,A2:D8, abUx,UNIQUE(TAKE(data,,2)),
 VSTACK({"Comp","Fund","Value"}, HSTACK(abUx, BYROW(abUx, LAMBDA(x,
  FILTER(TAKE(data,,-1), (INDEX(data,,3)=lk) * (INDEX(data,,1)=INDEX(x,1))
   * (INDEX(data,,2)=INDEX(x,2)),0))))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

Basically in the first formula, it finds first the unique first two columns (`abUx`), then use `BYROW` to iterate over `abUx` elements. On each iteration we use `FILTER` to select the values, that satisfy all the conditions, i.e. match all values of unique element (`x`) plus the lookup date (`lk`). We use `MMULT` to match both unique values of `x`, because it is an AND condition we equal to `2`. If the filter output is empty, then we return `0`. The rest is just to accommodate the output using `HSTACK` and `VSTACK`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be using MMULT so lambda iteration is not required:

```
=LET(r,  A2:D8,
     v,  F1,
     a,  INDEX(r,,1), b,  INDEX(r,,2),  c,  INDEX(r,,3),  d,  INDEX(r,,4),
     ab, UNIQUE(TAKE(r,,2)),
     ua, TAKE(ab,,1),  ub, TAKE(ab,,-1),
     mm, MMULT((TOROW(a)=ua)*(TOROW(b)=ub)*(TOROW(c)=v),d),
HSTACK(ab,mm))
```

`mm` checks that the values in column A and B equal the values of the unique version of these two columns and has the correct date value `v` in column C. If it does it sums the values of column D meeting these conditions.
The result is joined (stacked) with the unique values of columns A & B:

[image]

*Edit: improved the final part from `HSTACK(ua,in,mm)` to the shorter `HSTACK(ab,mm)` as suggested by David Leal*

Comment: this is great!, I was using `MMULT`, but I didn't think that `BYROW` can be avoided as you did. I guess you just need this at the end: `HSTACK(ab,mm)`

Comment: Since the date argument is a single argument we can use MMULT without lambda helper. If we would want it for several dates and want the results differentiated by date, we need to start using lambda MAP or BYROW/BYCOL.